# Failed to connect to remote VM while trying to configure Remote Debug of java application deployed on tomcat of Windows Server

Tags: java

I am trying to Configure Remote Debug in eclipse. Java Application is deployed on tomcat installed on windows server. [Attached a error screenshot].

Is it required to put server credentials also? If yes then how can I configure it with credentials?